# File_exists variable return false when using it with $_GET

Tags: php

I want to make a script which uses url variables to show pages and also check them before they load to prevent a php error, but the file_exists variable return false every time, here is the code:

```
<?php
if (!empty($_GET["page"])) {

    if (file_exists("any/" . $GET["page"] . ".php")) {

        include("any/" . $_GET["page"] . ".php");

    } else { echo "404"; }
} else {
    include("any/index.php");
} 
?>
```

that was in `index.php` and in the folder "any" was `index.php` and `file-1.php` which content was their name again.

I accessed: `index.php?page=index` which returned 404 from the file_exists variable, also that thing returned when I accessed `index.php?page=file-1` and that "404" message doesn't shown when I just accessed `index.php` or `index.php?page=` the problem doesn't exists if I remove that checker, but, it shows an include variable error at non existent files.

Comment: the path will be relative to the script location

Comment: if `file_exists` returns false, then the file does not exist (make sure the path is either relative to the main executing script or starts from the file system root)

Comment: the folder "any" is in the script folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you are using $GET["page"] rather than $_GET["page"] so I advise that you fix this and try again.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see that, I will test it tomorrow because now it's late and I need to sleep.

Comment: It happens sometimes. It's best to get some rest and look at a problem again when you are fresh in the morning :)